# Error when running pdflatex with beamerposter: beamerposter.sty not found

Tags: latex, pdflatex, beamer

I'm not a particularly experienced linux user, so bear with me if I say anything stupid.

I'm trying to make a poster using the beamerposter package within the beamer class. My "code" is fairly barebones right now;

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait, size=a1, scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\title{An Efficient Method for Characterising Noise in the Time Domain}
\author{Jim Barrett}
\begin{document}
Write something here
\end{document}
```

When I run the command

```
pdflatex poster.tex
```

It prints a bunch of things that are familiar from when I normally compile latex documents, and then it stops with the warning;

```
! LaTeX Error: File `beamerposter.sty' not found.
```

I've tried running things like

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
sudo apt-get install latex-beamer
```

But it just tells me that I've already got these things and they're up to date.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Let me know if there's any more details required to diagnose this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I found a solution. I needed to install a couple of extra things. I solved this by running

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Comment: Neither of these appear to install `beamerposter.sty`.